# VueMdl components not registered correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue 2.0 + VueRouter and trying to integrate VueMdl (https://posva.net/vue-mdl/#/usage) components into my project.

The site is running as a static resource served by Spring Boot using an embedded Apache Tomcat, so consider that the frontend isn't running in a NodeJs environment.

The problem is I can't figure out why the VueMdl components aren't registered correctly. The require() function doesn't work since it's specific to NodeJs and in the browser developer console, if I type VueMdl or console.log(VueMdl) ... I can see that the object is defined as well.

Thank you in advance,

app.js

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
})

// load main Vue.js app
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  components: VueMdl.components,
  directives: VueMdl.directives
})
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    [....]
  </head>
  <body>
    [....]
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/posva/vue-mdl/master/dist/vue-mdl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

error text

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <mdl-textfield> - did you register the 
component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
(found in <Anonymous> - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to import it :

```
var VueMdl = require('vue-mdl');
```

Comment: i'm not using nodejs, webpack or other new stuff ... I'll try to add http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Comment: Before this try to `Vue.use(VueMdl)` and see if it will work.

Comment: i'll let you know today ... a bit later

Comment: in the end I had to add require.js and rewrite a lot of code